# marshal_as returns the wrong value

Tags: string, marshalling, stdstring

In c++, I'm trying to write my own basic logical expression evaluator and I'm having an issue converting String^ to std::string value.
Here is a snippet of my code:

`String^ pattern = "[a-zA-Z ]+[>]+[ a-zA-Z]*" ;`

`Regex^ regex = gcnew Regex( pattern );`

`for( Match^ match = regex->Match( myExpression ); match->Success; match = match->NextMatch( ) )`

`{`

`if( match->Value->Length > 0 )`

`{`

`GetExpression(match->Value);`

`}`

`}`

Here is the private method definition of GetExpression():

`bool GetExpression(String^ matchedExpression)`

`{`

`-->     std::string normalString = marshal_as<std::string>(matchedExpression);`

`std::vector<std::string> mystring = StringSplit(normalString, " ", false);`

`return true;`

`}`

The line marked above is generating a value I am not expecting.  With a string input of "ax > bx", the value returned to normalString is an array of 7, with the first value of the array as "!" and the rest are empty.  Is there an error I made somewhere along the way?  myExpression seems to have the correct value of "ax > bx".  Thanks in advance.